# Optimizing this MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

**Table Schema**

For the two tables, the CREATE queries are given below:

***Table1:***   (file_path_key, dir_path_key)

```
create table Table1(
             file_path_key varchar(500), 
             dir_path_key varchar(500), 
             primary key(file_path_key)) 
engine = innodb;
```

***Table2:*** (file_path_key, hash_key)

```
create table Table2(
             file_path_key varchar(500) not null, 
             hash_key bigint(20) not null, 
             foreign key (file_path_key) references Table1(file_path_key) on update cascade on delete cascade)
engine = innodb;
```

***Objective*:**

Given a file_path *F* and it's dir_path string *D*, I need to find all those 
file names which have at least one hash in the set of hashes of *F*, but 
don't have their directory names as *D*. If a file *F1* shares multiple hashes
with *F*, then it should be repeated that many times.

Note that the file_path_key column in Table1 and the hash_key column in Table2 are indexed.

In this particular case, Table1 has around 350,000 entries and Table2 has 31,167,119 entries, which makes my current query slow:

```
create table temp 
        as select hash_key from Table2 
        where file_path_key = F;

select s1.file_path_key 
        from Table1 as s1 
        join Table2 as s2 
        on s1.file_path_key join 
        temp on temp.hash_key = s2.hash_key 
        where s1.dir_path_key != D
```

How can I speed up this query?

Comment: Is your question "How can I optimise my current query?"? In any case, please tell us what you actually want to solve.

Comment: Yes, JamWaffles, I'd like to speed it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what is the purpose of `temp` table, but remember that such table, created with CREATE .. SELECT, does not have any indexes. So at the very least fix that statement to

```
CREATE TABLE temp (INDEX(hash_key)) ENGINE=InnoDB AS 
SELECT hash_key FROM Table2 WHERE file_path_key = F;
```

Otherwise the other SELECT performs full join with `temp`, so it might be very slow.

I would also suggest using a numerical primary key (INT, BIGINT) in Table1 and reference it from Table2 rather than the text column. Eg:

```
create table Table1(
             id int not null auto_increment primary key,
             file_path_key varchar(500), 
             dir_path_key varchar(500), 
             unique key(file_path_key)) 
engine = innodb;

create table Table2(
             file_id int not null, 
             hash_key bigint(20) not null, 
             foreign key (file_id) references Table1(id) 
            on update cascade on delete cascade) engine = innodb;
```

Queries joining the two tables may be a lot faster if integer columns are used in join predicate rather than text ones.

Comment: Mushu, would that require me to add indexes like before?